# Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

------ Discover test started ------
Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:
'Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferSettingsHelper.MergeRunSettingsAndFindCompatibleSources(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Architecture ByRef, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.FrameworkVersion ByRef, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2>, System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable, System.String ByRef)'.'
Please contact the plugin author.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00) ==========

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by my own observations. After digging for 2 days and found nothing about this problem...
Well, the problem is caused simply because vstest engine is not updated. When I implemented those steps mentioned in the article "Authoring a new Visual studio unit test adapter" for Bhuvaneshwari K, sorry guys the admin says I can't post more than 2 hyperlinks and I prefered to post the links for Microsort down center for the solution. Anyway, you can google the article for more info.
When I compared the vstest of my build machine, and once again of my local test machine I found that the vesion of vstest.console was obsolete, although I see in the Hellp=>About menue that Update1 is already installed for both machines with the same version. So, I figured to install again the VS SDK and update 1, well in fact, repair not install. So I installed them from those links:
1- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SDK
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668
2- Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 KB2707250 from the link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35774
3- Restart the machine.
And the XMLTestAdapter is working like a charm in VS2012 in the build machine, still though I met some issues with TFSBuild to find the assemblies in a mapped folder under TFS2012 for the dlls of that adapter. I'll post a question for it in a new thread.

Comment: I had the same issue here, once I installed the **VS2012 Update 3** the issue went away :)

Comment: Well Fabito, when I encountered the issue, there was no Update 3 at that time :) so, I the answer is yes the solution is to install the latest update.

Comment: I also solved the issue for implementing XML Test Adapter under TFS Build server, I followed the steps in following link, but instead of putting **\*.js you need to put, **\*.xml, and it will work like a charm. This is the link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx?PageIndex=2&CommentPosted=true&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was that I had an issue in my Windows 7 System Environment variables.

To access:

1. Start Menu\Control Panel\System and Security\System
2. Click the Advanced System Settings link of the left.
3. Choose 'Environment Variables'

In the 'user variables for ***' section, click "New".

- Variable name = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
- Variable value = AMD64 (or whatever you find in the same corresponding 'system variable' area in the same window.)

close/reopen Visual Studio and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was adding the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package to the class library I wanted to test.